# GZip compression broken after three hard reloads

Tags: asp.net, iis, gzip

need help please... I've implemented an HTTP module that applies GZip compression.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Framework.Web.HttpModules
{
    public class GZipCompressionModule : IHttpModule
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// No need to compress image files (supposed to be they're already compressed, just a waste of CPU cycles)
        /// </summary>
        private static List<string> NoCompressFiles = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif" };

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
        }

        void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;

            // Web.Config value
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableGZipCompression"] == "true")
            {

                // Only applied if browser or client supports gzip
                if (context.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"]?.Contains("gzip") ?? false)
                {

                    // Not applied for some file extensions
                    if (!NoCompressFiles.Contains(context.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension))
                    {
                        context.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(context.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                        context.Response.Cache.VaryByHeaders["Accept-Encoding"] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

On first load, gzip works fine.
[image]

When I do a hard reload three times, gzip gets broken.
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to prevent http content to be like this? Not sure why this happens... thanks in advance.

Comment: GZip is not broken, problem is ASP.NET request pipeline, you are setting content encoding as gzip and when any error occurs while executing request, IIS sends text response which isn't gzipped... so browser gives this error.

Comment: UPDATE: I realized it only happens to assets greater than 3 kilobytes (e.g. 3.7kb raw still error, 1.5kb raw no error). Not sure why? Is there a need to await something in the module?